Google Map Web Scrapping by Python
"I am working on automating the process of retrieving distance and travel time between locations on Google Maps using Selenium. Previously, my script was working fine, but now it is encountering an issue. Specifically, it throws an error stating that no such element is found for the class name 'tactile-searchbox-input' or similar. I would appreciate any guidance or solutions to resolve this problem. Thank you!"
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from datetime import datetime as dt
import openpyxl
import sys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# set Chrome options to run headless
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

# create Chrome instance with the above options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
  
# assign url in the webdriver object
driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps/@33.9650923,71.5293553,9942m/data=!3m1!1e3?entry=ttu&g_ep=EgoyMDI0MTIxMS4wIKXMDSoJLDEwMjExMjMzSAFQAw%3D%3D")
sleep(5)
  
# search locations
def searchplace():
    
    Place = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "tactile-searchbox-input")
    Place.send_keys("33.983515, 71.447372")
    submit = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[8]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/button")
    submit.click()


# get directions
def directions():

    directions = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[8]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/button")
    directions.click()
  

# Start Point
def Start_Point():
    Starting_Location=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/input")
    Starting_Location.clear()
    Starting_Location.send_keys("33.99891877029553, 71.40166320892853") # Starting Location Input
    Search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/button[1]")
    Search.click()



# Printing Data
def Print_info():
        Distance = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]")
        Travel_Time = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[3]/div[9]/div[9]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]")
        return Distance.text,Travel_Time.text
# Set start time
start_time_str = '11:05 AM'  # Change to your desired start time
start_time = dt.strptime(start_time_str, '%I:%M %p').time()

# Set end time
end_time_str = '6:50 PM'  # Change to your desired end time
end_time = dt.strptime(end_time_str, '%I:%M %p').time()
i=0
while True:
    # Get current time
    now = dt.now().time()

    # Check if current time is within the specified time range
    if start_time <= now <= end_time:
    
        # get the current minute
            minute = int(time.strftime('%M'))
            Time = time.strftime("%H:%M %p")
            Date = time.strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
            # check if the minute is 15, 30, 45, or 0
            if minute in [5, 10, 38, 40,47,49,53,59]:
                sleep(3)
                searchplace() 
                sleep(20)
                directions()
                sleep(20)
                Start_Point()
                sleep(20)
                result = Print_info()
                sleep(25)
                # Open the workbook
                workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('D:\To be Managed\Dr.Rashid Work\Google Map\Google Map Data.xlsx')

                # Select the active sheet 
                sheet = workbook.active
                value1 = result[0]
                value2 = result[1]
                sheet.cell(row = i+2,column=1).value = Date
                sheet.cell(row = i+2,column=2).value = Time
                sheet.cell(row = i+2,column=3).value = value1
                sheet.cell(row = i+2,column=4).value = value2
                i = i+1
                        

                # Save the workbook
                workbook.save('D:\To be Managed\Dr.Rashid Work\Google Map\Google Map Data.xlsx')
                driver.close()
                driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
                driver.get("https://www.google.com/maps/@33.9886201,71.4011512,12.53z")
                sleep(60)
    elif now > end_time:
        # Exit the script when the current time is greater than end time
        sys.exit()   


Google does not like to be scraped and they change their sites constantly to make it harder. Except more such problems. They want you to use their API and throw in some coins.

It is much easier to use the official Google APIs. And they provide a free allowance up to a certain usage count.
